# Error "Cannot get property 'dependencies' on null object" in React Native Project just after Init project

Tags: android, react-native

I created a new React-Native project using react-native init AppName and when I tried to run in Android it throws **Cannot get property 'dependencies' on null object**  in line *@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 183* I am not sure why I am getting this exception. I didn't even do any changes in the project

Following is the command I use

```
react-native init Example
cd Example
npm i
react-native run-android
```

Version of react-native

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.3
```

Version of `npm - 6.11.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the @react-native-community/cli-platform-android using the below command solved my issue

```
npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
```

If the above doesnot resolve the issue, I temporarily fix the issue by updating the  native_modules.gradle like below

1. Search the line `json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(reactNativeConfigOutput)` in *node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle* file
2. Add `reactNativeConfigOutput = reactNativeConfigOutput.substring(4);` above that line.

[image]

Above fix the issue, but I think this is a temporary fix